# Error when trying to print out strings with a certain format using java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, match

I am reading a file that contains  the following:

127.0.0.1:8080

127.a.0.10:8081

127.0.1:8080.1

127.0.10.5:-8080

From there I have to print out the strings that match the following format. ###.#.#.#:####  This # represents any positive integer. 
When I run the code, it prints out the first line, and the statement "Not valid" for the next three strings, but it also marks an error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at homework4.Main.main(Main.java:36)

How can I fix this? Does it have to do with inputStream = null? 
Thanks in advance.

```
            public static void main(String[] args) 
            {
                Scanner inputStream = null;
                int count1 = -1;
                int i = 0;
                final String[] content = new String[200];
                {
                    try
                    {
                        inputStream = 
                                new Scanner (new FileInputStream ("input.txt"));
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("File input.txt could not be found or could not be opened");
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
                while (inputStream.hasNext())
                {
                    content[++count1] = inputStream.nextLine();
                }


                for (i=0; i <= content.length ; i++)
                {


                    if ( content[i].matches("^\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\:\\d{4}"))
                    {

                        System.out.println(content[i]);
                    }

                    else 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Not Valid");
                    }
                }
            }}
```

Comment: are you sure that 200 lines is enough?

Comment: Suppose the input contained just one line.  You do `for (i=0; i <= content.length ; i++)...`. The first time through this loop you will process the first line. What happens the second time through this loop?

Comment: content.length is 200, so you're going to try to loop over more lines of input than you have.  Since you aren't checking if `content[i]` is null, you're getting an exception after you run out of input lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your purpose is just print , then you don't need to store and don't required `String[] content` .. Just read the line and validate the line falls in particular pattern.

Move the condition to while loop.

```
 while (inputStream.hasNext())
   {
         String content = inputStream.nextLine();
          // Move the condition and check with content variable.
               if ( content.matches("^\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\:\\d{4}"))
                {

                    System.out.println(content);
                }

                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Not Valid");
                }
   }
```

In case your purpose is store the content . When you don't know the size / number of lines up ahead like this case , use `List` to store which can grow dynamically as required.

Like

```
List<String> contents = new ArrayList<String>()
```

And add the valid line with in valid condition like this.

```
  contents.add(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (content[i] != null) {   //check for this
    if (content[i].matches("^\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\:\\d{4}")) { ... }
    else { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Path path = Paths.get("input.txt");
    List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());
    for(String string: strings) {
        if (string.matches("^\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}:\\d{4}")) {
            System.out.println(string);
        } else {
            System.out.println("not valid");
        }
    }
```

If you use java 8, you can use Streams API

```
    Path path = Paths.get("input.txt");
    List<String> strings = Files.readAllLines(path);
    strings.stream()
            .forEach(string -> {
                if (string.matches("^\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\:\\d{4}")) {
                    System.out.println(string);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("not valid");
                }
            });
```

note : your regex contains a redundant escape

use

`^\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}:\\d{4}`

instead of

`^\\d{3}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\.\\d{1}\\:\\d{4}`

Comment: @user3574282 Did you try my answer ? Using Scanner and FileInputStream is a pretty old way to read content of a file.

Answer (score -1):

In your for-loop you go from 0 to length. The last index is although (length - 1)

Another problem is if your file has more than 200 lines